# How is IInterface used?

Tags: android

Recently, I was looking at some code where IInterface is used during the implementation of Java Reflection concept. In that part of code, the object of IInterface class is being used to invoke a method of Remote api.

I am little confused in here, how an object of a general IInterface class is used to invoke a method of the remote API( I am not aware of how Remote API classes are written).

So, I am concerned with how IInterface or IBinder is being used in this case.

Can somebody give some explanation on why IInterface would be used ? Though I searched for it, I could not get sufficent info on it.

Thanks in advance and please ignore if there are any errors.

Siva Kumar

Answer (score 0):

it was about Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) well it is used for remote service communication or IPC (inter process communication), if you know java rmi concept it basically work in such way i mean remote process communication , In android if you have service which is running remotely and you want to communicate with that service at that time it would came in picture.

For more information about aidl you can find out at here 
[Android AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)